# Помогите с проверкой на ссылки

Tags: python

Есть у меня бот в вк, у него есть плагин напоминания но плохие люди хотят его забанить вводя ссылки как сделать проверку на ссылки подскажите пожалуйста вот

```
command, text = self.parse_message(msg)
    if text.startswith("https:") or text.startswith("http:"):
```

пытался но не выходит он копирует текст( помогите пожалуйста

Comment: https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-validators.url

Comment: Нет, к сожалению это не то что нужно.

Comment: вы хотите узнать является ли строка text ссылкой, верно?

Comment: Да!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: согласно rfc очень многие строки могут быть ссылками. Лучше ограничения для вашего конкретного случая рассмотреть: является ли `ya.ru` ссылкой в вашем случае? A `/path`? Какой формат текста? (кто текст как ссылки интерпретирует? какие они правила используют?)

Comment: @Daeeros это именно то что нужно.

Comment: async def process_message(self, msg):
        command, text = self.parse_message(msg)

        proverka = validators.url(text, public=False)

        if proverka:
            return await msg.answer("Ссылки запрещенны.")
Я верно использую?(